# C# Conditional operator

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
age < 18 ? Console.WriteLine("Too Young") : Console.WriteLine("Old enough");
```

I am trying to get this line of code to run but keep getting CS0201 error on visual studio. Whats wrong?

Comment: `WriteLine` is a `void` method. You can't use that in a conditional.

Comment: [Error CS0201](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0201)

Comment: Sure. `age< 18 ? Console.WriteLine("Too Young") : Console.WriteLine("Old enough");` is also not a valid statement, regardless, as the error indicates. See @J...'s comment.

Comment: [?: operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 3):

The conditional operator requires an **expression**. `Console.WriteLine` is not an expression.
But a string is an expression, so you can say:

```
Console.WriteLine(age< 18 ? "Too Young" : "Old enough")
```

Or use an if-statement.